# Multiple fullScreenCover do call the same dismiss function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to achieve the following in SwiftUI 2.0:

1. I have to buttons, when clicked they show are custom time picker
2. On dismiss some variables are updated depending on the values picked and stored in the timePickerViewModel.model
3. The labels of the buttons are updated.

My problem: The dismiss function of the first button is ALWAYS called, even when I dismiss the timePickerView after pressing the second button. Thus breakTimeInSeconds gets never updated.

Any idea why? Thanks for your help :)

```
            Button(action: {                    
                timePickerViewModel.toggleShowTimePicker()
            }, label: {
                Text("Work for: \(quickStartViewModel.workTimeString)")
            })
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $timePickerViewModel.model.showTimePicker,
                                 onDismiss: {
                    let seconds = (timePickerViewModel.model.minutes * 60) + timePickerViewModel.model.seconds
                    quickStartViewModel.setWorkTimeInSeconds(seconds)
                    
                    timePickerViewModel.model.minutes = 0
                    timePickerViewModel.model.seconds = 0
                },
                                 content: {
                    TimePickerView(viewModel: timePickerViewModel)
                })
            
            // choose the length of breaks
            Button(action: {
                timePickerViewModel.toggleShowTimePicker()
            }, label: {
                Text("Break: \(quickStartViewModel.breakTimeString)")
            })
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $timePickerViewModel.model.showTimePicker,
                                 onDismiss: {
                    let seconds = (timePickerViewModel.model.minutes * 60) + timePickerViewModel.model.seconds
                    quickStartViewModel.setBreakTimeInSeconds(seconds)
                }, content: {
                    TimePickerView(viewModel: timePickerViewModel)
                })
```

Comment: Both `fullScreenCover` are presented on the same binding variable. The first one would always take precedence. You should use a different binding variable with the second `fullScreenCover`.

Comment: Use [fullScreenCover(item:onDismiss:content:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/AnyView/fullScreenCover(item:onDismiss:content:)) instead